# StackOverflow exception with SisoDB while storing a FileInfo entity

Tags: c#, nosql, document-database, sisodb

This questions refers to the [SisoDB](http://sisodb.com/) - an SQL-Server-based document database written in C#.

I am trying to store a FileInfo entity to the database. In order to avoid (potential) circular references I define the interface for the fields I need:

```
interface IFileData
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string DirectoryName { get; set; }
    long Length { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then try to store a FileInfo entity:

```
        var db = @"Data Source=C:\Temp\sisotest.sdf".CreateSqlCe4Db();
        db.EnsureNewDatabase();

        var info = new FileInfo(@"c:\config.sys");
        db.UseOnceTo().InsertAs<IFileData>(info);
```

This results in StackOverflow exception. Any ideas why it is so and how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SisoDb relies on the performant and outstanding serialization framework of ServiceStack.Text and my first test was to see if it can serialize a `FileInfo`, and that's where the `StackOverFlowException` seems to be generated. You can try this by either using `SisoDb.Serialization` (which is a copy of ServiceStack.Text) or by using ServiceStack.Text directly.

```
var json = info.ToJson();
```

As of now `InsertAs<T>` requires `T` to be an interface. `Insert<T>` and `InsertMany<T>` can handle interfaces, but also requires the actual item to implement the interface.

So as of now, to get further:

**1)** make a class out of `IFileData`.

```
public class FileData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DirectoryName { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**2)** Normally that should have been ok, but since the `FileInfo` can't be serialized to JSON, you need to, either:

**a)** Tell the ServiceStack serializer (contained in SisoDb.Serialization) not to include the properties causing the deserialization issue:

```
JsConfig<FileInfo>.ExcludePropertyNames = new[]{"Directory"};
```

**b)** Or you can make `FileData` wrap a `FileInfo`

**c)** Or you can make a custom wrapper `FileInfo2` which wraps `FileInfo`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = @"Data Source=D:\Temp\sisotest.sdf".CreateSqlCe4Db();
        db.EnsureNewDatabase();

        var info = new FileInfo2(@"D:\Temp\test.txt");
        db.UseOnceTo().InsertAs<FileData>(info);
    }
}

public class FileInfo2
{
    public FileInfo2(string cConfigSys)
    {
        var f = new FileInfo(cConfigSys);
        DirectoryName = f.DirectoryName;
        Length = f.Length;
        Name = f.Name;
    }

    public string DirectoryName { get; private set; }
    public long Length { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class FileData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DirectoryName { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```